# Change border color when var length less than 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Change border color when var length less than 1 ?

..................................................................................................................................................................

http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        var ex_se = $('#txt').val();
        var ex_se_lenght = ex_se.length;

        if(ex_se_lenght < '1')
            {
                // change border color id="txt" to red //
                alert('red');
            }
        else
            {
                // change border color id="txt" to black //
                alert('black');
            }
    }
})
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/9/ ... Here you go!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mana5tLg/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : change `$(window).laod` to `$(document).ready` and you are comparing length with string instead of integer so change `if(ex_se_lenght < '1')` to `if(ex_se_lenght < 1)`

**NOTE** - alert will be seen after 'ENTER' button pressed because condition `if(e.keyCode == 13)` is there.

code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var ex_se = $(this).val();
        var ex_se_lenght = ex_se.length;

        if(ex_se_lenght < 1)
            {
                // change border color id="txt" to red //
                alert('red');
            }
        else
            {
                // change border color id="txt" to black //
                alert('black');
            }
    }
})
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/7/)**

As Added by @Danko, to add border color create below css class and add / remove for red border

```
.alert {
    outline:none;
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

And JQuery :

```
if(ex_se_lenght < 1)
{
    $(this).addClass('alert');
    alert('red');
}
else
{
    $(this).removeClass('alert');
    alert('black');
}
```

**[Demo By Danko](http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/12/)**

Comment: +1 Here is an updated Fiddle changing the border color if you want to add in the answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/12/

Comment: @Danko, thanks for the jsfiddle link and +1. I have updated in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if(ex_se_lenght < '1')
{
    // change border color id="txt" to red //
    $("#txt").css('border-color', 'red');
    alert('red');
}
else
{
    // change border color id="txt" to black //
    $("#txt").css('border-color', 'black');
    alert('black');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66chLg61/13/)...

**EDITED: wrong selector...**

Answer (score 0):

Modify your js like this:

```
$('#txt').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var ex_se = $('#txt');
        var ex_se_lenght = ex_se.val().length;
        var color = ex_se_lenght < 1 ? 'red' : 'black';
        ex_se.css('border-color', color);
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/66chLg61/11/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#txt').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var ex_se = $('#txt').val();
            var ex_se_lenght = ex_se.length;

            if (ex_se_lenght < '1') {
                // change border color id="txt" to red //
                $("#txt").removeClass("black").addClass("red");  // remove previous added class black

            } else {
                // change border color id="txt" to black //
                $("#txt").removeClass("red").addClass("black"); // remove previous added class red
            }
        }
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2vafcdz/1/)